# Get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' when i'm trying to filter objects by logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to list all facilties owned by a user on a "facility list page" using the django rest framework and react. I tried the following to make this happen (admin_uid is a one to one field of the user owning the facility):

```
class FacilityListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = FacilitySerializer
    

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Facility.objects.filter(admin_uid=self.request.user)
```

I'm getting this error:

django          |     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
django          | TypeError: get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

This is what i had before which worked but listed all facilities:

```
class FacilityListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = FacilitySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Facility.objects.all()
```

Comment: Remove the `request` argument, you don't even use it in the method, you correctly use `self.request`

Comment: You need to show where you *call* the function. `TypeError: get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'` means that you call `get_queryset()` whereas Python expects you to provide an argument(`get_queryset(request)`, since you've added that in the declaration).

Comment: @Iain Shelvington: That gives me a different error: django          | TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f81441e5e20>.

Comment: @Matthias you either need to handle non-authenticated users somehow or make the view only available to logged in users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
class FacilityListView(ListAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = FacilitySerializer


def get_queryset(self, request):
    admin_uid = self.request.user.id
    return Facility.objects.filter(admin_uid=admin_uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do 2 things:

First - get_queryset function takes only one parameter, **self**, so remove **request** from fn defination.

Second - To get logged in user detail add permission_class = [isAuthenticated]

For not logged in user you can create a different view with permission class = allowany, coz your filter won't work for not authenticated users.